# Advanced Digitizing Panel bad value or bug?

Tags: qgis, line, measurements

This is my first post here.

What would cause the "Advanced digitizing panel" D (length) to show up wrong?

I'm in the US using WGS 84 as CRS.

If I add a feature (line) Advanced Digitizing Panels reads "d" value says 10.6, but using the measurement tool is 24ft and confirmed correct with Google Earth its 24ft.

Ultimately, my goal to know the length the line I'm adding.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Preferred measurements units setting in `Settings > Options`?

[image]

Comment: Yes. I selected feet. Upon more accurate testing, it appears the Advanced Digitizing Panel doesn't look at that setting and only uses meters. Unfortunately we use still use feet here in the us as the common field measurement units.

Comment: After checking this more, I found my original statement true of d value, but only when I'm in my main project. Example 9.42m shows 22.5feet measured but should be 30.9feet. If I start a new project using the same WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator(3857) and bring in the same shape file WGS 84 (4326) from our sql server the meters at least display correctly. I must have something wrong with my main project file. Perhaps I should get everything on the same CRS instead of letting "on the fly" change them as we migrated shape files. I will read up on the best way to convert them.

Comment: This now leads to question if we should use NAD83 4269 or stick with WGS 3857.

Comment: Good for you! I already had issues with area measurements when using on the fly projection for layers with different CRS.